# custom component: retrieve filter in view object

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

In my custom component...

- I display a list of countries as links and an extra-link called "dogs"
- once a country is clicked, a list of persons in that country is displayed (view: persons), by adding a filter `country` in the model.
- if "dogs" is clicked, a list of persons owning a dog is displayed (view: persons), regardless of the country they live in. This is done by adding a filter `dog` in the model.

**Task**
in persons-view, I want to display a title depending if country or dog is set as filter, e.g. "Austria"  or "Persons with Dogs".

**What I tried...**
reading the active filter from my view-object returns both filters always as `1`, even if it isn't set:

```
["filter.country"]=>int(1)
["filter.dog"]=>int(1)
["list.limit"]=>string(2) "20"
(...)
```

my model-file (snippet):

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $country = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.country', 'country', '',  null, false);
    $this->setState('filter.country', (int) $country);
    $dog = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.dog', 'dog', '',  null, false);
    $this->setState('filter.dog', (int) $dog);
    (...)
    parent::populateState($ordering, $direction);
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public function __construct($config = array()) {
    if (empty($config['filter_fields'])) {
        $config['filter_fields'] = array(
            'country',
            'dog'
        );
    }
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

view.html.php:

```
public function display($tpl = null) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();     
    $this->state = $this->get('State');
    (...)
```

I'm lost - is it nonsense to read the information from the state, or are my filters set incorrectly?

Comment: Are these filters declared in Model's constructor?

Comment: @WooDzu: Yes, see my edit. BTW hello again ;-)

Comment: It should work there's nothing unusual in your code. Perhaps there's something missing in your View. Since the state is not populated automatically it needs to be fired with $state = $model->getState() so then you can get a filter with $dog = $state->get('dog')

Comment: @WooDzu: I call `$this->get('State')` in the `function display`. When  I `echo $this->state->get('dog')` in `default.php`, I get no output at all :-(

Comment: @WooDzu: `$this->state->get('filter.dog')` is working like a charm, pls write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Good point. There's no chance $state->get('dog') would work. Well done for figuring this out

Comment: @WooDzu: Unfortunately, this works only at the first time going from countries to persons. On the second time, `filter.contry` and `filter.dog` will keep their values, regardless of the parameters in the url, e.g. in the url `dog=1`, `country` is not in the url, `var_dump($this->state)` will yield `filter-country = 2`and `filter.dog = 1`... I don't get it. Any clue?